# How to get relationship inside a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get the relationship inside a relationship using Laravel eloquent relationship.

Here what i tried:
This is my Order Model

```
public function orderProduct()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class);
}
```

And this is my OrderProduct Model

```
public function expiry()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ProductExpiryDate::class);
}
```

I tried to get the expiry date from the main Order Model like this

```
$deliveryOrder = Order::find($id);
dd($deliveryOrder->orderProduct()->expiry)
```

And it return me an error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$expiry
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Try `dd($deliveryOrder->orderProduct()->get())` to view collection results, Or you could get it like `Order::with('orderProduct.expiry')->find($id)`

Comment: Each order has multiple products, which each has one expiry. You'll have to iterate through the products (foreach) to get each expiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to do is to get a relationship with its sub-relationships.

This is easy to be done with the following:

```
App\Order::with('OrderProduct.expiry')->get();
```

From the Laravel documentation you can find the following regarding the **[Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)**
:

> To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax. For example, let's eager load all of the book's authors and all of the author's personal contacts in one Eloquent statement:

$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->get();

Comment: By using this $deliveryOrder = Order::with('OrderProduct.expiry')->find($id); I can get the orderproduct inside relations by dd($deliveryOrder->OrderProduct); but i can get inside to the expiry date too

Comment: Try `Order::find($id)->with('OrderProduct.expiry')->get()`

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: `$deliveryOrderProduct->expiry['expiry_date']` i use this to get into the relations but i dont know why it is in array form, not object? Can i call it as object?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because this is not an eager loading I would recommend

```
$deliveryOrder = Order::with('OrderProduct.expiry')->find($id);
dd($deliveryOrder->orderProduct->expiry)
```

And also when you use

```
$deliveryOrder->orderProduct() // this refers to relationship so
```

change it to this.

```
$deliveryOrder->orderProduct->expiry
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I get this error `Property [expiry] does not exist on this collection instance.`